# Make pdf data unselectable via php, converting everything to on image

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

So I am useing DomPDF to create my document. It draws everything on canvas. I need the resoult data on one page to become one image on this page. Make it unselectable, so it will look like it was scanned rather then created.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your solution you may want to look at this package [spatie/browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot). It is for Laravel, but you can see it making use of [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to take html and create either a PDF or an image.

From what I remember DomPDF is using an older rendering engine, where as puppeteer makes use of Google Chromes engine, so can render newer markup. So may even get a better looking result!

Comment: Ok, so I tried it but apparently it only works on linux (cause of Symphony/Process), my server is on windows. Tried to change Process to exec no luck.